# Better solution regarding annotation in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

I have the following code

```
     standard_text = "(%)"
    plotmath_text <- "I^2"
    g <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
g+ annotate("text", x = 4.3, y = 6.97, label =standard_text)+
 annotate("text",x = 4, y = 7, cex = 7, label = plotmath_text,parse = TRUE )
```

That produces a graph where in its upper right corner has the annotation

> I^2 (%)

Is there any way to create the same annotation using just annotate command once instead of two? I have tried to merge them into one command following [that page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/annotate.html) but I was always getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
annotate("text", x = 4, y = 7, cex = 7, label = "I^2 ~ ('%')", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

UPD: related questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994646/using-plotmath-in-ggplot2-with-percent-sign), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955200/subscripts-in-r-when-adding-other-text).